Developer Tools do not record/show anything in Console/Network tabs. Microsoft Edge
I need to inspect a bug in a website on client's machine. The bug happens on client's machine (multiple users, same company). Even though I have exactly the same Microsoft Edge version (130.0.2849.56) I can not reproduce the bug and I have none of the issues that are mentioned bellow.
Issue 1. When we try to inspect what is happening we (me and the clients, over a video call) open Developer Tools and are not able to use the website - you can not click, drag, scroll or do any action within the website besides just moving the mouse cursor. However if you click on "Learn more" button (which appears in Network tab) some Microsoft website gets opened in a new tab and if you return to our website you can start using it - scrolling, clicking and so on.
Issue 2: When we start doing an action which makes http requests or logs something to the console nothing gets logged/shown in the Console/Network tabs. No filters are being used to filter console/network traffic.
I have asked the client if they have any policies put in place to restrict user's actions with Developer Tools and their IT staff reported that do not use such policies.

Apparently the website was being run in Internet Explorer mode and in this mode Microsoft Edge's Developer Tools have a very limited functionality. I had to run %systemroot%\system32\f12\IEChooser.exe and then select the tab/website I want to properly inspect with Developer Tools. What a nonsense Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer are...
